# arithmatic operation in linq using entity framework mvc C#

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, linq, lambda

In the method below I have to calculate a final price as per the following formula but that's giving me an error. How I can do following operation with the following query?

```
public JsonResult GetAllPanditBookList()
{
    var plist= db.TB_PBooking.Select(hc => new { 
        hc.PB_ID, 
        hc.PB_PRICE, 
        hc.PB_SPRICE, 
        hc.USER_ID,  
        hc.REG_DATE, 
        hc.STATUS,
        ((hc.PB_PRICE *hc.PB_SPRICE) /100) as FinalPrice,
        hc.PAYMENT_TYPE,
        hc.TB_UserReg.FULL_NAME,
        USERMOB=hc.TB_UserReg.MOBILE_NO 
    }).OrderByDescending(x => x.PB_ID).ToList();

    return Json(_templeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Always take time to format your questions properly, this will help others to read and understand clearly. Often people ignore questions that are not properly formatted.

Comment: ok thank you for providing suggestion I will definitely improve it

Comment: additionally if you have an error, you should mention precisely what the error message says, and which line is throwing it. It's not always possible to tell from the code alone, and we shouldn't need to spend time to try and work it out anyway, when you already know the information. Here it appears you're confusing SQL syntax with C# syntax (you should look up what the `as` keyword does in C#, its meaning is totally different from the SQL meaning) but if the error is not a syntax error then very often it's not possible to know it just from reading the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public JsonResult GetAllPanditBookList()
{
    var plist= db.TB_PBooking.Select(hc => new 
    { 
        hc.PB_ID, 
        hc.PB_PRICE, 
        hc.PB_SPRICE, 
        hc.USER_ID,  
        hc.REG_DATE, 
        hc.STATUS,
        FinalPrice = hc.PB_PRICE * hc.PB_SPRICE /100,
        hc.PAYMENT_TYPE,
        hc.TB_UserReg.FULL_NAME,
        USERMOB = hc.TB_UserReg.MOBILE_NO 
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.PB_ID)
    .ToList();

    return Json(_templeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you need to convert prices from `string` to `int` you should change the type for these columns in your DB.

You should be able to parse `string` to `int` the following way (please note I didn't test this code):

```
var plist= db.TB_PBooking.Select(hc => new 
    { 
        hc.PB_ID, 
        hc.PB_PRICE, 
        hc.PB_SPRICE, 
        hc.USER_ID,  
        hc.REG_DATE, 
        hc.STATUS,
        hc.PB_PRICE,
        hc.PB_SPRICE,
        hc.PAYMENT_TYPE,
        hc.TB_UserReg.FULL_NAME,
        USERMOB=hc.TB_UserReg.MOBILE_NO             
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.PB_ID)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(hc => new 
    { 
        hc.PB_ID, 
        hc.PB_PRICE, 
        hc.PB_SPRICE, 
        hc.USER_ID,  
        hc.REG_DATE, 
        hc.STATUS,
        FinalPrice = (int.Parse(hc.PB_PRICE) * int.Parse(hc.PB_SPRICE)) /100,
        hc.PAYMENT_TYPE,
        hc.FULL_NAME,
        hc.USERMOB 
    })
    .ToList();
```

Calling `.OrderByDescending(x => x.PB_ID)` before `AsEnumerable()` lets the database order the result.

Comment: how I can convert string values to int in above expression because PB_PRICE  and PB_SPRICE    are in string format

Comment: @MANGESHUKADE just [cast them to int (or maybe decimal, if that's more suitable)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/casting-and-type-conversions#explicit-conversions). But why are you storing numbers as strings in your database? That's the real problem here. Fix your underlying data structure and it all gets much easier.

Comment: @MANGESHUKADE Though it's possible to convert `string` to `int`, I would store these values in `money` format in DB like ADyson said.

Comment: FinalPrice = Convert.ToInt64(hc.PB_PRICE) * Convert.ToInt64(hc.PB_SPRICE)  gives an error as         Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int64 ToInt64(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Try int.Parse(hc.PB_PRICE)

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: I solved the issue by changing datatype but also above solution work for me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as @Thangadurai mentioned, Please take time to provide good explanation of the question which you are asking.

It is recommended to create a DTO for your result Objects and return DTO as following

```
      public class PanditBookDTO
      {
            int PB_ID;
            string hc.PB_PRICE;
            string hc.PB_SPRICE;
            int hc.USER_ID;
            DateTime hc.REG_DATE; 
            int hc.STATUS;
            int FinalPrice;
            hc.PAYMENT_TYPE;
            string FULL_NAME;
            string USERMOB
      }
```

And use this class as below :

```
    public JsonResult GetAllPanditBookList()
    {
        var plist= db.TB_PBooking.Select(hc => new PanditBookDTO()
        { 
            hc.PB_ID, 
            hc.PB_PRICE, 
            hc.PB_SPRICE, 
            hc.USER_ID,  
            hc.REG_DATE, 
            hc.STATUS,
            FinalPrice = (Convert.ToInt32(hc.PB_PRICE) * Convert.ToInt32(hc.PB_SPRICE)) /100,
            hc.PAYMENT_TYPE,
            hc.TB_UserReg.FULL_NAME,
            USERMOB = hc.TB_UserReg.MOBILE_NO 
        })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.PB_ID)
        .ToList();

        return Json(_templeList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Even in the future if you are changing your query, your response would be type safe.

Comment: got an error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @MANGESHUKADE I have updated the answer. Accept the answer if useful and solves your issue.

Comment: I solved the issue by changing the datatype in database